# Fetch employee information by selecting employee_id from DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

My database has employee id, name, Email, address, and phoneno. I have used a dropdownlist for selection of employee id, for this I wrote this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class Employeedetails : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=REVATI-PC;Initial Catalog=Test_Database;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    string query;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        query = "select Employee_ID from Employee";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
        }

        con.Close();
```

but by clicking on those particular id, I did not get other information. For this I used `SelectIndexchanged` event and write a select query

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        string query = "select Employee_ID from Employee where Employee_ID='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
        con.Open(); 
}
```

But it's not working

Comment: It doesn't look like you're ever executing your query in DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged()...

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    string empname="";
    string query = "select * from Employee where Employee_ID=@value1";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1",DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString());
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     while (dr.Read())
    {
        empname=dr["Employee_Name"].ToString();
    // and so on
    }
    con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are seeing is two-fold. You are selecting only the employee ID during your query, not any additional information, and you do not appear to be running your query if the function you posted is complete. To select additional information, choose either select * (as below), or select specific column names and read them out from the reader by column name

Try updating your selectedIndexChanged function to this:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "select * from Employee where Employee_ID='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";

    conn.Open();

    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(dr["<column_name>"].ToString());
    }

    con.Close();
}
```